# Sublime Text 2 regex matching with >9 back-references

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to capture several groups within a string and reorder them using a regex. However once I reach greater then 9 back-references, they do not replace as I expected.

Eg:
This is a bit of a contrived example, but it should illustrate what's happening.

```
Input string: abcdefghij
Find What: ^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$
Replace With: \10
Expected output: j
Actual output: a0
```

I also tried:

```
  Replace With: $10
```

Instead of `\10` or `$10` inserting the contents of the tenth grouping parens, it inserts the contents of the first grouping parens follower by "0".

UPDATE:

This does work using `$10` in newer versions of Sublime Text, but it is way better to use the `${10}` syntax as described below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
${10}
```

I just tried it and that worked for me.

I also tried using find:

```
^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$
```

Replace with: `$10`

And it worked. I'm using v2.0.2 build 2221 however. The same with `\10` doesn't work, but works as you described in your question.

It might be worth noting as well that many of the regex engines replace are shifting from the `\#` format to the `$#` format so that's maybe why `$#` is working better for me even without braces.

Though now, if you wanted to replace with the 10th capture followed by a number (e.g. $100) the engine will look for the 100th capture group and for your example, will replace with nothing.

Comment: Using "\{10}" yields "{10}", not "j" as expected. But ${10} worked. Thanks!

Comment: @karlwilbur Right, that's why I didn't using `\{10}` in my answer :)

Comment: @karlwilbur Also, you use backticks (`) for preformatted code :)

Comment: I believe the technical name for the example string (.)(.) ... is a "Rack".

Comment: @happyD Any source/reference for that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to put braces around

```
${10}
```

Make this habit!

It becomes even more helpful when you actually want to append `$1` with a number `0`. Then you may require `${1}0`